# Where is the correct place to assign an interface listener in adapters?

Tags: java, android, interface, android-recyclerview, adapter

Sometimes in a RecyclerView adapter it is helpful to call functions when you click on items in each row, so I defined an interface and assigned the listener like so:

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {
    private List<SomeObject> mSomeObjectList;
    private Context mContext;
    private RowClickListener mListener;

    public interface RowClickListener {
        void someFunction(SomeObject someObject);
    }

    public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<SomeObject> objects) {
        mContext = context;
        mSomeObjectList = objects;
        mListener = (RowClickListener) context;
    }
    //...
```

Is this the correct way to do it? I notice that when people assign listeners in Fragment classes they usually do it in the OnAttach method, which doesn't really seem to exist here in the case of an Adapter. What's considered the appropriate place here?

Comment: when do you create listener object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather defining it in `Adapter` i would suggest to use it in `Fragment` or `Activity`.

Define seperate class for `Interface` or define it in `Fragment/Activity`.

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity implements RowClickListener
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        .
        .
        .
        MyRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(context,list,this);
    }

    @Override
    public void someFunction(SomeObject someObject){

    }
}

public interface RowClickListener {
    void someFunction(SomeObject someObject);
}
```

and in your adapter class

```
private RowClickListener mListener;

public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<SomeObject> objects, RowClickListener listener) {
    mContext = context;
    mSomeObjectList = objects;
    mListener = listener;
}
```

Comment: I like this approach but I don't even know why! Is there any particular reason why you did it this way?

Comment: generaly i used to define seperate class for interface so that i can use it multiple times, there is no other reason.

Comment: I normally put interfaces within the classes.. how do you make them separate classes?

Comment: There is no difference in defining it as seperate class, it is same as java class or activity or fragment. just write interface code in seperate file, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, passing the listener through Adapter constructor is fine. But, check the type before casting.

```
public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<SomeObject> objects) 
{
        mContext = context;
        mSomeObjectList = objects;

        if(context instanceOf RowClickListener)
        {
            mListener = (RowClickListener) context;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How would one define the interface normally? Do most people use separate files or nest them inside another class?

Comment: If the interface is used only in single class, it is ok to define the interface that class. If you implement the interface at many classes, then consider to define the interface in separate file.